# Ubuntu 12.04 ATI Driver

Tags: drivers, kernel, ati, versions

Good day,
So i just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (i'm now to Ubuntu and even Linux systems, but i've bored of the lot of brainfuck with Windows systems)

So, i installed Steam and then 2 games (Left 4 Dead 2 and Killing Floor)
But then i realized both of them runs slow as hell... I searched on google for what can cause this, and i found that it must be the Graphics Driver... The system settings says it is "Unknown" but according to 13.10 it might be the Gallion 4.0 (or something like this)

So, i want to install the official AMD Catalyst Drivers...
But the problem is, every time i'd like to install it push a sexy error to my face: "Some of the tools are missing"
I checked the .log file and it can't find the "version.h" for the kernel 3.11.0-18-generic
(Before i pudated the system programs it said 3.11.0-15-generic)
So, i checked it, the 3.11.0-15 have the version.h inside, but the 18 does not...
I could not find any solution in google, somebody maybe can help me how to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do from a fresh install is to update and then install additional hardware. You'll have the options to install a stable driver that works with Steam without throwing up out of date driver messages at you. They may not be the fastest drivers but they are faster than the Gallion drivers at the moment.